# How can I display only the rake tasks that are defined in my app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

If I type `rake -T` I am forced to drink from the firehose, and filter visually through all the default tasks provided by Rails, to hunt for any that I've written but forgotten about, or that another developer has written.

This is a terrible pain.  There must be some reasonable solution.  How can I show only the tasks provided by the current Rails app?

Answer (score 0):

You could filter the results if you know the `keyword`:

```sh
$ rake -T keyword
```

You could also exclude results with keyword `firehose`:

```sh
$ rake -T | grep -v firehose
```